# problem with bash echo function

Tags: bash, echo

how do i print using echo in bash so the row wont "jump" abit to the right cause of the length of the Variable can u please help me with a command that do so

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the `printf` shell command:

```
$ printf "%5d %s\n" 1 test
    1 test
$ printf "%5d %s\n" 123 another
  123 another
```

Comment: still cause of the first variable the column "jumps" abit to the right the suggestion you gave me helps with the spaces between variables but not ignoring the length of each one of them

Comment: If you want further help, you're going to have to give an example of what you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

To trim leading whitespace inside a variable you can use Bash parameter expansion:

```
var="   value"
echo "${var#"${var%%[![:space:]]*}"}"
```

Comment: You can omit the inner set of quotes: `echo "${var#${var%%[![:space:]]*}}"`

Answer (score 0):

Use tabs to separate your columns.

```
echo -e "$var1\t$var2"
```

or, better, use `printf` to do it:

```
printf "%s\t%s\n" $var1 $var2
```

Or, as [**Greg Hewgill** showed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433372/problem-with-bash-echo-function/3433383#3433383), use field widths (even with strings - the hyphen makes them left-aligned):

```
printf "%-6s %-8s %10s\n" abcde fghij 12345
```